# Github Action File only setting one environment variable

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a dev.env file location under src/dev.env which looks like below.

```
oidc_token_url="TEST"
oidc_client_id="TEST"
oidc_scope="TEST"
oidc_introspect_url="TEST"
oidc_user_info_url="TEST"

db_type="TEST"
db_host="TEST"
db_port="TEST"
db_user="TEST"
db_name="TEST"
db_service_name="TEST"
```

Using github actions I wanted to add two key/values to this file utilizing github secrets. I added the below to my github action file. Not posting the whole file but just a snippet of the issue.

```
- name: Generate .env.dev file
        run: |
          touch src/dev.env
          echo "oidc_client_secret=\"$OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET\"" >> src/dev.env
          echo "db_pwd=\"$DB_PWD\"" >> src/dev.env
          cat src/dev.env
        env:
          OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET }}
          DB_PWD: ${{ secrets.DB_PWD }}
```

For some reason the only thing being appended to my dev.env file is "db_pwd" while "oidc_client_secret" is being completely ignored. Below is the output from the GHA runner.

```
oidc_token_url="TEST"
oidc_client_id="TEST"
oidc_scope="TEST"
oidc_introspect_url="TEST"
oidc_user_info_url="TEST"

db_type="TEST"
db_host="TEST"
db_port="TEST"
db_user="TEST"
db_name="TEST"
db_service_name="TEST"
db_pwd="***"
```

Why is it only adding one of the two variables? I also double checked my secrets and they were both in GH. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified it by printing it on the terminal using `echo`?